# Why BeautifulSoup returns [ ] randomly?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having a weird behavior of BeautifulSoup where sometimes i get response `[]`

So, I'm doing some scraping to get some fields from a webpage and it happens that randomly it fails

I mean, I'm looking each 5 minutes in the same page to see if field changed and even if nothing changed randomly (it appears to be) i get response `[]`

So i get the id of the website page in a early stage and for each page i request in this step the age shown in the page - Example id = 79088
The code is the following (bear with me with the prints, I'm using it for debug)

```
    for id in ids:
        soure = requests.get('https://www.infofunerais.pt/pt/funerais.html?id=' +  id, headers=siteHeaders).text
        soup2 =BeautifulSoup(soure, 'html5lib')
        print ("\n")
        print ("id antes de idade " + str(id))
        print (soup2.find_all('span',class_='idade-detail',limit=Config.limit))
        for idade in soup2.find_all('span',class_='idade-detail',limit=Config.limit):
            print ("idade id   " + str(id))
            print ("idade text    " + str(idade.text.strip()))
            try:
                ages.append(idade.text.strip())
            except:
                print ("idade map definida")
                ages.append(str("??"))

            print ("Tamanho ages " + str(len(ages)))            
            print ("\n")
```

So the "normal" response is:

```
id antes de idade 79088
[<span class="idade-detail">97 anos</span>]
idade id   79088
idade text    97 anos
```

The issue is that randomly I'm getting:

```
id antes de idade 79088
[]
```

Any idea what can make this happen?

I'm doing this inside of a Qthread since I don't want to block ui while scrapping, can this be the problem?

Edit:
I have tried the code provided by @WorkAholic with slight modification to run in loop each 60 seconds and after a while e got same issue

```
id 79088
97 anos
id 79092
85 anos
id 79141
92 anos
id 79150
91 anos
id 79155
87 anos
id 79195
99 anos
sleeping 60 secs
id 79088
97 anos
id 79092
85 anos
id 79141
92 anos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/PiClock/stackof.py", line 49, in <module>
    SrartInfofuneraisPT(id_person)
  File "/home/pi/PiClock/stackof.py", line 42, in SrartInfofuneraisPT
    run(InfofuneraisPT().LoggerParser(id_person))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/pi/PiClock/stackof.py", line 37, in LoggerParser
    await self.Parser(session, id_person)
  File "/home/pi/PiClock/stackof.py", line 28, in Parser
    anos = soup.find("div", {"class": "detailfalecido_header"}).find("span", {"class": "idade-detail"}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Could be that the server occasionally returns an empty response, or an error response that doesn't contain your expected markup

Comment: @motto I don’t know, it could be the server side, I don’t manage it. What is weird is that just after this request I do same request but to get another field in same page and it never fails. It’s failing only for this field

Comment: That certainly is odd, but I'd start by printing / saving the response payload for cases where you're getting an empty list. See if there's anything unusual in there.

Comment: In your own words: what do you think this response means? What do you think the response should be instead, and **why**? Just to make sure, you understand that this value is a *list*, right? And that `[]` simply means an empty list, one with no elements in it? So - the confusion is about why there aren't any elements? or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes I understand what is the response and when I get not empty response I know how to manage. The problem is sometimes I get the empty response for some reason

Comment: What happens if you try visiting the web page in a browser? Will you always get `<span class=idade-detail>` tags? Why? What do they actually represent, and **why shouldn't it be possible** that a valid page result from the server just... doesn't have any of them? In other words: "I'm doing some scraping to get some fields from a webpage" - **why should we expect** that the web page would **always** have those fields?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel first thing is I’m checking same webpage working 5 minutes. This field is representing the age of the person and it’s not changed after created first time. So in my mind there is no reason why in a random search it’s not there but hundreds of other times it’s there. The page it’s not changing. I guess the issue is on the response side. Some overlapping or some error I cannot understand for the moment

Comment: It seems like this is an issue simply with the web site, and not with the code. Clearly it doesn't *cause a problem* for the code, if an empty list is received, right? I don't think there is a question *about programming* here. We don't operate the web site, so if there is a problem on their end we cannot do anything about it.

Comment: The question could be with code in case I’m missing some parameters or not operating the thread in a good way or even if I’m having some trouble with timing. Anyway I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Serch id + recursion, hope I helped you

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from pyuseragents import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from asyncio import run


class InfofuneraisPT:

    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = {
            'authority': 'www.infofunerais.pt',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
            'accept-language': 'ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            'user-agent': random(),
            }
            
    async def ParserAnos(self, session, link):

        try:

            params = {'id': f'{link.split("=")[-1]}',}

            async with session.get(link, params=params) as response:
                anos = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml").find("div", {"class": "detailfalecido_header"}).find("span", {"class": "idade-detail"}).text

                print(f'id {link.split("=")[-1]}')
                print(anos)

                return [link.split("=")[-1], anos]

        except:

            return await self.ParserAnos(session, link)


    async def Parser(self, session):
        count = 1

        while count < 2500:

            print(f'https://www.infofunerais.pt/pt/funerais.html?pg={count}')

            async with session.get(f'https://www.infofunerais.pt/pt/funerais.html?pg={count}') as response:
                blocks = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml").find_all("div", {"class": "f_bloc"})

            links = [block.find("a").get("href") for block in blocks]

            data = [await self.ParserAnos(session, link) for link in links]

            count += 1


    async def LoggerParser(self):
        async with ClientSession(headers=self.headers) as session:
            await self.Parser(session)


def SrartInfofuneraisPT():
    run(InfofuneraisPT().LoggerParser())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SrartInfofuneraisPT()
```

Output:

```
https://www.infofunerais.pt/pt/funerais.html?pg=5
id 79105
98 anos
id 79104
55 anos
id 79103
93 anos
id 79102
67 anos
id 79101
86 anos
id 79100
91 anos
id 79099
85 anos
id 79098
74 anos
id 79097
62 anos
id 79096
97 anos
id 79095
92 anos
id 79094
88 anos
id 79093
68 anos
id 79092
85 anos
id 79091
74 anos
id 79090
91 anos
id 79089
83 anos
id 79088
97 anos
id 79087
```

Comment: Let me try that and come back to you. My issue is not that my code doesn’t work, normally it’s working for hundreds of times , the issue is that randomly it’s returning a empty response

Comment: Try adding sleep or adding params to get. To speed up the software, you can also create a session, I hope my advice will help you

Comment: WorkAholic please check my edit above. Got the same issue with your code.
I think this issue is coming from the thread usage, in a old version of the app i use it in the main thread and i have no issues at all. app running 24/7. Any hint?

Comment: Good morning, can you send me a list of id?
I'll check the id, maybe there will also be an error and it's the site then

Comment: Example - id 79088,id 79092,id 79141,id 79150,id 79155,id 79195

Comment: Exactly so, since the site does not have time to load a larger volume, I decided everything by recursion

Comment: If so, the script has been updated